# OpenLayers - How to construct OpenLayers.Bounds

Tags: openlayers-2

I would like to create Bounds for a layer but I am not sure in what order I have to provide the min_x / max_x and min_y / max_y coordinates.

is it correct to put it in that order: min_y, min_x, max_y, max_x

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([{{ wms.min_y }}, {{ wms.min_x }}, {{ wms.max_y }}, {{ wms.max_x }}, ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [Bounds constructor](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.OpenLayers.Bounds) says:

> bounds    {Array(Number)} [left, bottom, right, top]

So you need to provide these parameters as numbers

`var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds.fromArray([wms.min_x, wms.min_y, wms.max_x, wms.max_y]);`

Answer (score 1):

The full documentation for the above answer is at

http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html

Comment: Hi! Welcome to GIS StackExchange, thank you for your post.